# Is there any way to create run time "python class"(model) that contains same fields in PostgreSQL database table in Odoo?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

Suppose, I've a PostgreSQL table named colors and it has columns like red, green, blue, black.

The thing is that, I don't have python class(Model) for that table yet; because I want to create it run time based on database table. i.e if insert new column in a colors table it will be automatically added to the python class(Model) as a field with Float type directly(run time).

Comment: You do `add column` not `insert column` ? You want to have to opposite of ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) and it is not good. I suggest you to answer the question: `Why I need that !` or update your question, may be there is a better approach.

Comment: This process is called reflection. SQLAlchemy has an [extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) for it.